# How to create full access from all ip in kibana and create a login and password to log in to the cab using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm creating a test elasticsearch aws using terraform, I can't give full access from all ip addresses + how do I automatically add a username and password to log in to kibana? I read the manual s on github but I didn't understand how to do ithelp me pls

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es" {
  domain_name           = var.domain
  elasticsearch_version = var.version_elasticsearch

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = var.instance_type
  }
  snapshot_options {
    automated_snapshot_start_hour = var.automated_snapshot_start_hour
  }
  ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = var.ebs_volume_size > 0 ? true : false
    volume_size = var.ebs_volume_size
    volume_type = var.volume_type
  }

  tags = {
    Domain = var.tag_domain
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_service_linked_role" "es" {
  aws_service_name = "es.amazonaws.com"
  description      = "Allows Amazon ES to manage AWS resources for a domain on your behalf."
}


resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain_policy" "main" {
  domain_name     = aws_elasticsearch_domain.es.domain_name
  access_policies = <<POLICIES
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "*"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Resource": "${aws_elasticsearch_domain.es.arn}/*""
    }
  ]
}
POLICIES
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access control for AWS Opensearch is documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ac.html and the kind of access you are looking to achieve is called 'fine-grained-access-control' which is explained in detail at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html.

I know this terraform resource is not documented well to explain these different access types, which is why I am sharing the modified version of your code to get your task going with additional arguments you were missing your code.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

variable "master_user_password" {
  type    = string
}

# Elasticsearch domain
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es_example" {
  domain_name           = "example-domain"
  elasticsearch_version = "OpenSearch_1.0"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "t3.small.elasticsearch"
  }

  ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 10
    volume_type = "gp2"
  }

  encrypt_at_rest {
    enabled = true
  }

  node_to_node_encryption {
    enabled = true
  }

  # This is required for using advanced security options
  domain_endpoint_options {
    enforce_https       = true
    tls_security_policy = "Policy-Min-TLS-1-2-2019-07"
  }

  # Authentication
  advanced_security_options {
    enabled                        = true
    internal_user_database_enabled = true
    master_user_options {
      master_user_name     = "es-admin"
      master_user_password = var.master_user_password
      # You can also use IAM role/user ARN
      # master_user_arn = var.es_master_user_arn
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Domain = "es_example"
  }
}

resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain_policy" "main" {
  domain_name     = aws_elasticsearch_domain.es_example.domain_name
  access_policies = <<POLICIES
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_elasticsearch_domain.es_example.arn}/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICIES
}
```

This code  is working for me and I was able to access OpenSearch Dashboard from my browser and was able to login using the credentials I specified in terraform code.

Comment: @Iceforest did you try this solution ?

Comment: sry,, I haven't had time yet, I think 1 or 2 January

Comment: very nice, its working, my version elasticsearch 7.10